SSIS Package fails to execute on server after updating VS from 2019 version to 2022
The package is a simple copy CSV template, execute procedure, write to csv then email task. I have an OLEDB connection manager and an Excel and SMPT connection. A  recent IT update meant we were no longer able to use Visual Studio 2019 and we have VS 2022 version. I reconfigured the package as we have some new data and realised that the new version of VS does not have SQLNCLI11.1 provider. Instead I selected the OLE Db for SQL server connection. Deploy was fine however on execution using the Job agent (32 bit run) it fails with this error message :

Package:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has
occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available.
Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server" Hresult: 0x80004005
Description:  "[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECCreateCredentials()).]SSL
Security error

Any ideas what the issue is here?
Much appreciated

Sounds like a certificate issue; are you using a self signed cert on the SQL Server?

I have just checked and it seems that the server is using self assigned certs!

Then you ned to implement a valid certificate, force trust of the certificate (less secure) or not encrypt your connection (not secure).

how would i force trust of the certificate please?

Does this answer your question? "The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted" when connecting DB in VM Role from Azure website

Native Client, i.e. SQLNCLI11, is deprecated since 2018. You need to download and use its replacement: Microsoft OLEDB Driver. You should see it in the connection string as MSOLEDBSQL

Since 2014, @YitzhakKhabinsky . SQL Server 2012 was the last version of SQL Server where SQLNCLI was the "preferred" driver.
